# What would be the "cheapest" way to check for updates periodically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Basically I'm writing an ASP.NET MVC application that though a javascript sends a GET request every 30 seconds, checking if a certain row in a table in the database has changed.

I've been looking at the OutputCache attribute but it doesn't seem like it would work since it would just cache the content and not really check if an update was made.

What would be the "cheapest" way to do this? I mean the way that burdens the server the least?

Comment: Probably [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) with push notification when there's a change in the database (and that could be either tracked manually or by `SqlDependency`, depending on the database)...

Comment: One thing to keep in mind -- if you have alot of users on the system then a quick HTTP get is typically far cheaper than long polling or websockets as your server is pretty good at handling a few million quick gets, espeically with caching but not so good at holding a few tens of thousands of socket connections open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Probably SignalR with push notification when there's a change in the database (and that could be either tracked manually or by SqlDependency, depending on the database)...*

I used Wyatt Barnett's suggestion and it works great.

Thanks for the answers - appreciate it.

Btw I'm answering it since I can't mark his comment as answer.

Answer (score 0):

A HEAD request may be faster, but not guaranteed to be, but it is worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use something to stream the change to you, the cheapest way is to use an API that takes a date, and returns a boolean flag or an integer stating whether a change occurred.  Essentially it's polling, and this would be minimal because it's the smallest response back and forth, if a SignalR or some other message receive process isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want it to do, have you considered long-polling? Eg, make the GET/POST request using javascript and allow the server to withhold the reply until your 'event' happens.

Answer (score 0):

`OutputCache` works perfectly. But it's expiration time should be a divider of your polling time, like 10 sec for - in this case - 30 sec on client size.

I'm not an expert on EF, but if your database supports triggers; that would be an option and you can cache the result for a longer period (like say 1 hour) unless a trigger is set.

But if your record is being updated very fast, trigger would be costly.

In that case I would go with Caching + a time-stamp mechanism (like versions in a NoSQL db, or time-stamp in Oracle).

And remember that you are fetching the record every 30 seconds, not on every change on the record. That's a good thing, because it makes your solution much simpler.